# Does OFONO(Open source telephony) supports Sierra EM7590 and EM74XX series?

Tags: usb-modem, modem-manager

Does OFONO(Open source telephony) supports Sierra EM7590 and EM74XX series? I am using linux 16.04 and linux 22.04 version.